# Jquery Click fail to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a html as :

```
 <ul style="list-style-type: none" id="AgeFilter">
                        <li><a href="#.">- Kid</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#.">- Teen</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#.">- Young Adults</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#.">- Adults</a> </li>
                    </ul>
```

and i tried implementing the jquery as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#AgeFilter li a").click(function () {
            alert(1);
              var temp=$(this).html().split("- ");

              $("#<%=SelectAge.ClientID %>").val(temp[1]);
               $("#<%=BtnAgeFilter.ClientID %>").click();
        });
});
```

The Problem is,
the alert doesn't call on any href click.Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: put it in a `$(document).ready`

Comment: Sir it is in document.ready

Comment: Try using $("#AgeFilter li a").live('click',function(){ ...

Comment: it look fine....do you check Error log ?

Comment: add ");" at the end
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#AgeFilter li a").click(function () {
        alert(1);
        var temp=$(this).html().split("- ");
        $("#<%=SelectAge.ClientID %>").val(temp[1]);
        $("#<%=BtnAgeFilter.ClientID %>").click();
    });
}); // missing );
```

Comment: np, try to look at console to find syntax errors, use firebug, etc.

Comment: @PetrFort: actually his code had no error. see the edit history. it was lost on formating done by some other user.

Comment: I checked the history and you are right, thanks, but it is little but confusing to connect right answers (comments) to the question with edit history.